# Get all elements containing a class with querySelector

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, html2canvas

For changing some styles in a class I'm using `querySelector()`:

```
el.querySelector('.fa fa-car').style.display = "none";
```

This works fine for one element but if there are more elements containing this class and I want to change the display to none for all of them, this command only deletes the first occurrence of it leaving the next ones untouched.

I tried to do it with `querySelectorAll()`:

```
 el.querySelectorAll('.fa fa-car').style.display = "none";
```

But this one returns an error message:

> html2canvas: TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined

any ideas about how to get all the elements containing a specific class and perform an operation on them?

Comment: you can use `getElemntsByClassName` of javascript

Comment: @NikhilGhuse that will have the same issue as `querySelectorAll()`, though, as it returns a collection

Comment: Yes but you can use foreach with collections

Comment: My point is that by itself it doesn't help OP as it presents them with the same problem they're asking about; ie. 'how do I work with a collection?'

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> The Element method [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns a static (not live) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.

Use [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all the elements. Then  use `forEach()` to set the style in each element:

```
var elList = document.querySelectorAll('.fa.fa-car');
elList.forEach(el => el.style.display = "none");
```

**Please Note:** Some older version of IE (<8) will not support `querySelectorAll()`. In that case use

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.fa.fa-car'))
```

Comment: Note that `nodeList.foreach()` is won't work in any version of IE, should you need to support it.

Answer (score 3):

`querySelectorAll()` returns a collection of elements. To change their styling you need to loop through them.

Also note that your selector appears to be invalid. Given the FontAwesome class rules I presume you need to select by both classes. Try this:

```
Array.from(el.querySelectorAll('.fa.fa-car')).forEach(function() {
  this.style.display = "none";
});
```

Alternatively, as you've tagged the question with jQuery, you could just simplify all that to just:

```
$('.fa.fa-car').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

querySelector only select one element, to select all element you can use querySelectorAll

```
[].map.call(el.querySelectorAll('.fa fa-car'), n => { n.style.display = 'none'; })
```

Comment: Which is why the OP is asking the question - how does he do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use method querySelectorAll()
See https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselectorall.asp

You are getting error because querySelectorAll returns an array.Iterate over it and then use style.display

Answer (score 0):

You could do all your operation by iterating the occurence of this class and of course by help of some if clauses.

```
$('.fa.fa-car').each(function(){
     $(this).css('color','white');
})
```